# Permutations in the set $(1,2,3,4,5)$ where the first term is prime

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Let $S$ be the set of permutations of $(1,2,3,4,5)$ whose first term is a prime.

If we choose a permutation at random from $S$, what is the probability that the third term is equal to $2$?

I found that the total number of permutations is $3*4^4$ and the number of permutations where $2$ is in the 3rd spot is $4!$. Is this correct?

Comment: Two mistakes here : first the total numbers of permutations should be $3*4!$. Then, when you count the number of permutations where $2$ is in the $3$rd spot, you should only consider permutations for which the first term is a prime.

Comment: So it would be $\frac{2*3*2*2}{3*4!} = \frac{24}{3*4!} = \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Why $2*3*2*2$ ?

Comment: Sorry I meant 2*3*1*2

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: @132479 so the answer is not $\frac 13$ but $\frac 16$

Comment: @RadialArmSaw I think he understood that ;)

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I wasn’t telling- just asking for clarification.